# Can I get a German resident permit?

Tags: germany, immigration, resident-permit, non-citizens

I'm an Algerian, 25 years old and I have a Danish residence permit valid for 3 months. Although I have an Algerian passport, the rest of my family (parents and siblings) live in Germany and they all have German citizenship.

Since my family lives in Germany, is there a way that I can be granted a German residence permit after the Danish resident permit expires? Could I apply for it without going back to Algeria?

If not, what are my chances of hiring an immigration lawyer?

Comment: @DJClayworth You mistyped the URL

Answer (score 4):

Since you are an adult, wishing to stay with your relatives is not a reason for Germany to grant you a resident permit.

You can get a resident permit related to a job, a study program at any Germany university or any refugee state protection...

Comment: How about hiring a lawyer?does it help for me to stay with parents?

Comment: @KevinDrizzy hiring a lawyer won't give you any rights you don't already have.  A lawyer might be able to inform you about a path to a residence permit that you didn't know about, or didn't know was available to you, or didn't know you could afford, but no more than that.

Answer (score 3):

Your legal base as an adult relative is:

- Aufenthaltsgesetz

  - Kapitel 2 - Einreise und Aufenthalt im Bundesgebiet (§§ 3 - 42)

    - Abschnitt 6 - Aufenthalt aus familiären Gründen (§§ 27 - 36)

      - § 36 Nachzug der Eltern und **sonstiger Familienangehöriger**

Commonly called "Family reunification".

The law basically says that family reunification for minors and spouses is allowed ([§29](https://dejure.org/gesetze/AufenthG/29.html)), others only in specific cases of hardship ([§36](https://dejure.org/gesetze/AufenthG/36.html)).

Those cases of hardship are decided case-by-case. Normally, courts will rule that the binding between parents and non-minor children are not of such a kind that separation constitutes a case of hardship. "außergewöhnliche Härte" (case of hardship) applies for example if the child cannot live a life of their own, maybe because of a (mental) disability, chronic illness or trauma.

Whether you can find a lawyer that is so good (or sleazy) that he can bend the law to your will, I cannot say. Maybe you can find some other option to stay in Germany that does not rely on your relatives already being here.  Maybe you qualify for a [blue card](http://www.bluecard-eu.de/) on your own?

Comment: Just being Algerian is no base for political asylum. You will be rejected.